# Apply css attribute from ko.observable in knockoutjs?

Tags: css, html, knockout.js

In my knockout viewmodel, I have a property which returns a percentage from 0 to 100.
I want to apply this value to the css width of a div.

How do I do this?

```
<div ???? percentageProperty ????>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`style` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) to add or remove one or more style values to the associated DOM element:

```
<div data-bind="style: { width: percentageProperty() + '%' }">&nbsp;

</div>
```

Note: you need to write `percentageProperty()` with the `()` if your `percentageProperty` is a `ko.observable` and of course you don't need the `+ '%'` part if your `percentageProperty` already contains a string like `59%`.